# How to access data in child component of query called in parent component in rtk query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

How can I access the data of the query called in the parent component, inside a child component without prop drilling.

For example, if in parent.js I call the `getPost` query

```js
const {data} = useGetPostQuery();
```

then how can I access this data further down the hierarchy?

Answer (score 5):

There are two options I see:

1. The "right" answer way - is to use a selector from API slice to access the cached data which is already in rtk-q's Redux store. Let's say we have `posts` API slice definition. So we'll be able to access some particular cached post directly with a selector, provided by rtk-q:

.

```
const selectPost = posts.endpoints.getPost.select(postId);
```

`selectPost` - is a memorized selector, gererater by rtk-q for a particular `postId`. To fetch the data - that you'll need to pass the app state in, and it will return the expected post from the cache, that your parent component fetched before.
Inside the component it can be used with `useSelector` like:

```
const { data: post } = useSelector(posts.endpoints.getPost.select(postId));
```

Some more details here:
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#selecting-users-data

2. And a pretty straightforward way - is just to use the same query code in your child :).
   Even it sounds weird\smelly - there is nothing wrong with it, due to you making your component standalone\decoupled, and it will get this data anyway - even will be used outside the parent component. But if it will be used in a case you described, as a child - it will just fetch data from the cache, with no real API call, so with no harm to performance. And it looks even more clear than selectors.

I prefer exactly this approach, and I feel it keeps the code more consistent - I'm just declaring that "I need that data" in a component, and don't care if it was fetched before or not, keeping all the components decoupled from knowing about any others component, making it cohesive.

It's somehow touched here:
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-8-rtk-query-advanced#cache-data-subscription-lifetimes

Offtopic bonus: In a case when you don't need the `post` data on a parent's component and want to fetch it only to improve responsiveness - you may use the `usePrefetch` hook. For example - on the "Edit" button hover, it will make an API call, put the data in the cache, so `post` will be available for children instantaneous.

More here:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/prefetching

Answer (score -2):

- If you want data to be available to all the rendered components then use Context. But, frequent changes in the context will cause permanence issues as the entire tree will get rerendered if the component is not designed properly.
- Another option is to use Redux in the app to manage the states.
  https://redux.js.org/introduction/core-concepts
- Local storage is another option but will not recommend this.

Answer (score -4):

The easiest way to send data from parent to child through props but if you want to do it without props you should use other stratigies like: localStorage,cockies or redux.

Comment: Using localstorage or cookies is not a great solution when we are already trying to use a state storage mechanism. And in my opinion, redux is already in use. So, the question is more like how to retrieve the query's response.